# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Autogenerated>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to load a local json file information in List.But I don't know my emulator is showing something like this.[image: My Emulator]

and my code is [image: My main code]

Here is my debug console pic.[image: Debug Console]

I tried many stackflow ans to solve this but was unable.
Can anyone Help me out?

Comment: Please when posting a question, copy paste your code in a code block instead of posting pictures of code to make it easier for us to help you, that being said, can you see if changing this line `body: FutureBuilder(` to this `body: FutureBuilder<List<Autogenerated>>` will solve the issue?

Comment: Also you can try this: `List<Autogenerated> items = (data.data ?? <Autogenerated>[]) as List<Autogenerated>`

Comment: Thanks h8moss Your first comment solved my problem.